# The 'props' parameter implicitly has a type of 'any' when use theme with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, themes, styled-components

I'm trying to typing the theme of my project in React Native using styled-components, typing the styled-components DefaultTheme, but when I try to use it, it isn't working:

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Zh0.png)

I want to see the options when I put dot after props, but it's typed with 'any'.

I created the theme like this:

`theme.ts`

```
export default {
    colors: {
        primary: '#8bc542',
        tertiary: '#fede19',
        secondary: '#c2d047',

        text: '#5e5e5e',
        background: '#f6feef',

        light: '#FFFFFF',
        dark: '#000000',
    },

    fonts: {
        regular: 'Poppins_400Regular',
        medium: 'Poppins_500Medium',
        bold: 'Poppins_700Bold',
    },
};
```

`styled.d.ts`

```
import "styled-components";
import theme from "./theme";

declare module "styled-components" {
    type ThemeType = typeof theme;

    export interface DefaultTheme extends ThemeType {}
}
```

`App.tsx`

```
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { Home } from './src/screens';

import theme from './src/global/styles/theme';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Home />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
styled.SafeAreaView<{ theme: THE_THEME_TYPE }>`
    flex: 1;
    padding: 26px;
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.background};
`
```

Comment: Actually I'm tryng to re-type the styled-components DefaultTheme, that's why I have the file styled.d.ts.

Comment: but you have - as far as I see - not given the props a type. if you say that theme is of the type DefaultTheme then perhaps this should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).